# finding platforms at Karlsruhe

Tags: germany, train-stations

I'm traveling from Munich to Karlsruhe, where I'll change trains for Besancon.  I'll have 19 minutes to change trains with a big suitcase & a carry-on bag.  Is there any way for me to find out at which platform I'll arrive & from which I'll leave?  I haven't bought the tickets yet, because I want to get the logistics worked out first.  Thank you.

Comment: 19 Minutes is normally plenty of time to move from one platform to another. However, your first train has a chance to be delayed by a few minutes. To account for the case that you miss the connection due to a delay, you really want to book both trains on the same ticket, so that in case you miss the connection, your ticket remains valid and you can take the next train. Should this happen, you probably need to visit the ticket booth in Karlsruhe to get your seat reservation for the TGV changed.

Comment: Even when you buy your ticket as separate items, if you miss your train due to a delay, visit the ticket window to ask for help. Very often train companies do honor the tickets even when bought separate.

Comment: Not a duplicate but this question might be helpful: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/115309/how-much-transfer-time-do-i-need-at-karlsruhe-hauptbahnhof?rq=1

Comment: What's weird is that I have played around at bahn.de and I did not find a train from Munich to Karlsruhe from which you can catch the daily TGV from Karlsruhe to Besancon with 19 minutes to spare. Is their web site broken? However, bahn.de says the TGV departs from track 1.

Answer (score 8):

You'll find details at bahn.de. Enter your planned trip and in the details section of any selected trip you'll find which track (Gleis) the train will be on. Then you can go to the station info and I saw a nice PDF with a map of Karlsruhe Hbf. I was looking at this in German, don't know if there is a possibility to have the site in English (Edit: at the top of the homepage you can select languages)

Answer (score 4):

If you select **punctuality** [on the bahn.de website](https://www.bahn.com/en/view/index.shtml) and enter your booking code, it will show you

- If your trains are on time
- The arrival/departure platforms
- Further connections

Please be advised that these platforms can change on short notice. But don't worry, your platform and the platforms of connecting trains are announced when arriving in a station.

Aside from that, 19 minutes is more than enough time, even if you have to ask for directions. Karlsruhe has a [relatively small station](https://www.bahnhof.de/bahnhof-de/bahnhof/Karlsruhe_Hbf-1019530).

Comment: This approach however requires that the OP booked the ticket as an online-ticket with DB (rather than with SNCF).

Comment: Alternatively, the train number can be entered. That would also work with SCNF tickets.